# Conditional SQLite check constraint?

Tags: sql, sqlite, constraints

I have a table defined by the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id       integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  status   text NOT NULL,
  enddate  date,
  /* Checks */
  CHECK (status IN ("Current", "Complete"))
);
```

I'd like to add a constraint using [CHECK](https://sqlite.com/lang_createtable.html#check_constraints) that requires `enddate` to be non-null **if** the `status` is "Complete".

Is this possible? I am using SQLite v3.6.16.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

How about:

```
CHECK (status = "Current" or (status = "Complete" and enddate is not null))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Is this the only way? In future I may have a larger number of statuses and the check could grow quite large.

Comment: When constraints get very complex, the approach is typically to put a layer in front of the table to enforce it.  Like a stored procedure layer, or a data access library.

Comment: Well, SQLite currently does not support Stored procs, so only way to achive it will be either having triggers or implementing the logic from the UI layer.

Comment: @Rezzie I think if the statuses grow, you can still use this construct with a little modification: `CHECK (status <> "Complete" or (status = "Complete" and enddate is not null))`; notice that it has no mention of `"Current"` at all. You'll need to keep `CHECK (status IN ("Current", "Complete"))` as well to validate possible `status` values. If multiple statuses require `enddate`, you should be able to change `<>` and `=` to `NOT IN` and `IN`.

Comment: This could really be shortened down to `(status <> "Complete" or enddate is not null)` There's no need recheck the value of status, if you're checking the second half of the or statement, you already know `status = "complete"`

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing stopping you from having multiple `CHECK` constraints on a single table. IMO the simplest and most easily expandable solution:

```
CHECK (status IN ("Current", "Complete"))
CHECK (status <> "Complete" OR enddate IS NOT NULL)
```

This uses the fact that *if A then B* is logically equivalent to *either not A or B*.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id       integer PRIMARY KEY,
  status   text NOT NULL CHECK (status IN ('Current', 'Complete')),
  enddate  date NOT NULL
);
```

This will work in SQLite, with the `CHECK` constraint written inline. I changed double quotes to apostrophes so it can be used in PHP.

Comment: Did you read the question? He even put the important part in **bold** what you just dismissed.