# How can I constrain an SQLite database field using Perl?

Tags: perl, sqlite

I'm building a SQLite database using Perl.

Here's an example of my code so far

```
my $stmt = qq(
  CREATE TABLE PBS_control_data (
    Antibody        TEXT  PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Raw_data        FLOAT NOT NULL,
    Normalized_data FLOAT NOT NULL
  )
);

my $rv = $dbh->do($stmt);
if ($rv < 0) {
  print "$dbh::errstr";
}
else {
  print "Table created";
}
```

I have six items in the `Antibodies` field and I want to constrain the field so that you *must* enter one of those six names as a way of preventing mistakes.

How can this be done?

Comment: I have tidied your Perl code so that I could understand it. I hope you prefer my version, but please roll back my change if you wish. But your question puzzles me. It looks like you know enough SQL to be able to check whether an input string matches any of the `Antibody` fields. My only comment is that if you have only six records, and your database is either static or never has more than a single user, then you may as well store the table in memory for *much* faster access

Comment: I'm afraid I've cheated a little bit - I'm pretty new at programming and I'm following a tutorial (here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_constraints.htm ). It says to use the CHECK function  but only gives a numerical example. 

The reason why I've chosen to store my data in a database rather than a flat file is because I have a multi-dimensional data set that I keep getting confused with. 

And I believe that the table is already stored in memory (or I don't fully understand what you mean by that). Thanks.

Comment: I'm not really clear about your context. You *can* create an in-memory SQLite database, but the data is volatile and vanishes when your process exits. It's far more common that the database is kept as a disk file, but then I'm wondering why you have just six records kept in a database. It sounds like you just need a Perl hash, and involving SQLite will only make things more complex for you. But perhaps there is more to your application than you have explained?

Comment: I'm looking to create a database to store experimental data. The data will have three fractions, three time points, three repeats, six antibodies and six different experimental conditions (hence why I'd rather try and use a database than a spreadsheet).

Comment: Okay, then I think you're looking in the wrong place. You should use simple Perl code to verify the data you're entering into the database. You *could* apply a `CHECK` constraint to the column and just try inserting whatever the user enters, but that would be sloppy programming. Kinda like pushing all of your groceries into your fridge, and throwing things away if it goes green and smells

Comment: I think you can make a table in sqlite that uses "CHECK" expressions to verify string values see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615477/conditional-sqlite-check-constraint remember to handle the errors nicely though http://www.perlhowto.com/dbi_handling_database_errors

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking in the wrong place. You should use simple Perl code to verify the data you're entering into the database

You *could* apply a `CHECK` constraint to the column and just try inserting whatever the user enters, but that would be sloppy programming

Answer (score 1):

To let the database check that a filed value has one of six values, use a CHECK constraint like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
   MyField TEXT CHECK(MyField IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f')),
   [...]
);
```